# Matching a master collection to a transactional status collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My issue is rather specific so I'll try to explain my setup first.

I have a collection called `clients`, which is a master list of all clients. The model for it is:

```
{
    id: String,
    organizationId: Number,
    networkId: String,
    deviceSerial: String,
}
```

(irrelevant properties removed)

I also have a collection called `clienttransactions`, which is a list of when clients have gone online or offline. So each time a client comes online, it adds a record saying it came online (`online: true`), and vice-versa for when a client goes offline (`online: false`). The model for that looks like this:

```
{
    clientId: String,
    deviceSerial: String,
    networkId: String,
    organizationId: Number,
    ts: Number,
    online: Boolean
}
```

`ts` is a unix timestamp in seconds. Also if you're wondering why I need all those foreign keys on each record, it's because of the way the API where I get this data from works. So just ignore that.

issue:

Given a `deviceSerial`, `networkId`, and `organizationId`, I want to find all clients that were online at any point between a given time frame (given a start time and end time in epoch seconds).

Possible edge case: There could be times when a client came online before the given start time, and stayed online until after the given end time. In this case, there will be no transaction record within the time frame, but the client should still be seen as online.

Accounting for this case is what I'm having the most trouble with, since I can't simply just search for online transactions between the time frame. If there are no transactions for a client in the time frame, then I need to search outside the time frame to see if the last transaction made before the start time for that client was an online one.

I'm not super well-versed on the aggregation pipeline yet, so this is as far as I got:

```
const startTime = 1550601742;
const endTime = 1550599341;

ClientTransaction.aggregation([
  {
    $match: {
      organizationId: 600381,
      networkId: 'N_651896046061895525',
      deviceSerial: 'Q2MN-3CUN-6GQM',
      ts: {$lt: endTime}
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$clientId',
      lastStatus: {
        $max: '$ts'
      },
      online: {
        $last: '$online'
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

I think I'm halfway there with this. It finds all transactions for unique clients before the end time, but stops before process of checking if the client was actually online during the time frame.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for all clients whose latest activity is an online activity before start time or has online/offline activity between start and end time.

So something like should work

```
ClientTransaction.aggregation([
  { $match: { 
      organizationId: 600381, 
      networkId: 'N_651896046061895525',
      deviceSerial: 'Q2MN-3CUN-6GQM',
      ts: {$lte: endTime}
    }
  },
  { $sort:{"clentId":1, "ts":-1 } },
  { $group: {
      _id: '$clientId',
      latest: {
        $first: '$$ROOT'
      }
  }},
  { $match:{
     $or:[
       {"latest.online":true,"latest.ts":{$lt:startTime}},
       {"latest.ts":{$gte:startTime, $lte:endTime}}
     ]
  }}
]);
```